# Render ember-view into defined container

Tags: javascript, ember.js, view

I'm trying to get my head around emberjs, and my issue right now is that I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            Hi, {{name}}!
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the `ember-view` is being rendered before the closing `</body>`

```
    <div id="ember298" class="ember-view">
        Hi, Alex!
    </div>
</body>
```

instead of where I was expecting it, inside `div.col-lg-12`. And I just can't figure why is that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Handlebars templates are supposed to be declared at the top-level of your HTML, with the markup inside the script tag, not the other way around. For instance, something like this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                Hi, {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
</body>
```

This allows Ember.js to properly detect the template and fill it in when you get to the appropriate route. Look at the [example JSBin for Ember](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) and  you'll get a better idea of how to write templates. You might also want to read [Ember's guide on template basics](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/).

EDIT: Something that might also help is to remember that Handlebars templates don't have to go in your HTML file. I put mine in `.hbs` files and compile them to Javascript. The Handlebars script tag is really just there for convenience. In other words, never put in a script tag inside of your markup, just use the Handlebars expressions and Ember will know what to do.